# Extract headings from a MS Word document in Python

Tags: python, ms-word

I have an MS Word document contains some text and headings, I want to extract the headings, I installed Python for win32, but I didn't know which method to use, it seems the help document of python for windows does not list the functions of the word obejct. take the following code as example

```
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("MyDocument")
doc = word.ActiveDocument
```

how can I know all the functions of the word object？I didn't find anything useful in the help document.

Comment: You are accessing the win32com API for Word, which isn't a part of Python, so there will be no documentation for it within Python.

Comment: thanks, so how can I find the document of a COM API, or is there any method to list all the functions of a COM object?

Comment: RocketDonkey links to it in [his/her answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14238229/722121).

Comment: @Lattyware Ha, guess it is kind of an ambiguous name ('his').

Comment: @RocketDonkey I did quickly check your profile for clues. I thought it was better than just presuming XD

Comment: @Lattyware Ha, I do the same thing and always get frustrated when there are no clues (even though I guess I'm a bad offender myself!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Word object model can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Your `doc` object will contain these properties, and you can use them to perform your desired actions (note that I haven't used this feature with Word, so my knowledge of the object model is sparse). For instance, if you wanted to read all the words in a document, you could do:

```
for word in doc.Words:
    print word
```

And you would get all of the words. Each of those `word` items would be a `Word` object (reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258018%28v=office.12%29.aspx)), so you could access those properties during iteration. In your case, here is how you would get the style:

```
for word in doc.Words:
    print word.Style
```

On a sample doc with a single Heading 1 and normal text, this prints:

```
Heading 1
Heading 1
Heading 1
Heading 1
Heading 1
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
```

To group the headings together, you can use `itertools.groupby`. As explained in the code comments below, you need to reference the `str()` of the object itself, as using `word.Style` returns an instance that won't properly group with other instances of the same style:

```
from itertools import groupby
import win32com.client as win32

# All the same as yours
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("testdoc.doc")
doc = word.ActiveDocument

# Here we use itertools.groupby (without sorting anything) to
# find groups of words that share the same heading (note it picks
# up newlines). The tricky/confusing thing here is that you can't
# just group on the Style itself - you have to group on the str(). 
# There was some other interesting behavior, but I have zero 
# experience with COMObjects so I'll leave it there :)
# All of these comments for two lines of code :)
for heading, grp_wrds in groupby(doc.Words, key=lambda x: str(x.Style)):
  print heading, ''.join(str(word) for word in grp_wrds)
```

This outputs:

```
Heading 1 Here is some text

Normal 
No header
```

If you replace the `join` with a list comprehension, you get the below (where you can see the newlines):

```
Heading 1 ['Here ', 'is ', 'some ', 'text', '\r']
Normal ['\r', 'No ', 'header', '\r', '\r']
```

Comment: Well, this will print the heading many times, since a heading may contains many words.

Comment: @zdd Yeah, it was more of a proof of concept :) I'll amend with one possible way of grouping them together, but definitely can't claim it is the 'accepted' win32 way.

Comment: @zdd Added an update which I hope will help (definitely an interesting API :) ).

Answer (score 4):

convert word to docx and use python docx module

```
from docx import Document

file = 'test.docx'
document = Document(file)

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name == 'Heading 1':
        print(paragraph.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Google Drive SDK to convert the Word document to something more useful, like HTML, where you can easily extract the headers.

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Comment: As another alternative, I think you could also use the win32com to save the document as html and then extract the headers.